# How to shorten this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

Therefore, this study evaluated DOM products, as a contribution to the validation of the DOM products, by comparing them with products derived, by implementing the Land Model algorithm, from the observations of FGOMY.

Comment: Leaving aside for a moment that this is too localized, the question is also very poorly fleshed out. It is impossible to provide a meaningful answer as long as you supply no context whatsoever. Depending on the context, the sentence can be shortened to two words, omitted altogether, or will have to be expanded to twice the length.

Comment: Use fewer commas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an understanding of the relation between the algorithm implementation and the observations,any suggestion would not be of much value.  Having said that, here is an attempt to make your sentence more compact and crisp.

> "As a validation exercise, a comparative study of DOM products and
>   products derived from the Land Model algorithm implementation of FGOMY
>   observations has been carried out."

Alternatively, you may also say

```
*"... derived from the application of Land Model algorithm over FGOMY observations..."*
```

Answer (score 1):

You should explain the intent of the sentence. Since you did not, I have presumed the one that makes most sense:

> This study is an evaluation of DOM products, to validate such products, by comparing them with products derived from implementation of the Land Model algorithm and the observations of FGOMY.

Comment: The second comma is probably wrong.